# Pasar variable PHP entre modales que no estan en la misma hoja

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery

tengo un error que me dice $datos undefined ya se por que pasa pero quiero pasarla a boton que tiene un modal los guarda como cadena asi: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que crear un php individual aparte y coger los datos de mi modal donde estan los check box o como, aparte obviamente recupero el id depende de la fila o row. Ayuda porfavor!

Answer (score -3):

si tu aplicación es totalmente web te recomiendo que uses Local Storage, es muy fácil de usar y puede resolver tu problema.

LocalStorage y sessionStorage son propiedades de HTML5 (web storage), que permiten almacenar datos en nuestro navegador web similar a las cookies.

Local Storage guarda información que permanecerá almacenada por tiempo indefinido, sin importar que el navegador se cierre.

Session Storage almacena los datos de una sesión y éstos se eliminan cuando el navegador se cierra.

Ventajas:
- Permiten almacenar entre 5MB y 10MB de información (texto y/o multimedia)
--La información está almacenada el dispositivo del cliente 
-NO es enviada en cada petición del servidor, a diferencia de las cookies
-Utilizan un mínimo de peticiones al servidor para reducir el tráfico de red
-Previenen pérdidas de información cuando se desconecta de la red
- La información es guardada por domino web

```js
/*Funcion de Capturar, Almacenar datos y Limpiar campos*/
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#boton-guardar').click(function(){        
        /*Captura de datos escrito en los inputs*/        
        var nom = document.getElementById("nombretxt").value;
        var apel = document.getElementById("apellidotxt").value;
        /*Guardando los datos en el LocalStorage*/
        localStorage.setItem("Nombre", nom);
        localStorage.setItem("Apellido", apel);
        /*Limpiando los campos o inputs*/
        document.getElementById("nombretxt").value = "";
        document.getElementById("apellidotxt").value = "";
    });   
});

/*Funcion Cargar y Mostrar datos*/
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#boton-cargar').click(function(){                       
        /*Obtener datos almacenados*/
        var nombre = localStorage.getItem("Nombre");
        var apellido = localStorage.getItem("Apellido");
        /*Mostrar datos almacenados*/      
        document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML = nombre;
        document.getElementById("apellido").innerHTML = apellido; 
    });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center><h1>Ejemplo - localStorage</h1>
              
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombretxt"> <br>  <br>   
<input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" id="apellidotxt"><br>  <br>
<button id="boton-guardar">Guardar</button><br>
           
<hr />
Nombre almacenado:
<label type="text" id="nombre"></label><br>                          
Apellido almacenado:
<label "text" id="apellido"></label><br>

<button id="boton-cargar">
Cargar elementos
</button>
</center>
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es de muy baja calidad, no solo no responde directamente el problema (el cual tampoco es claro en la pregunta) sino que sugiere ir y ver «tutos», esto debería ser un comentario.

Comment: Añade mayor detalle a tu respuesta, ejemplifica, argumenta para dar mayor calidad al contenido.

Comment: Edite para evitar conflictos.